# Drop user object in Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

Anyone help me regarding Oracle query to drop user object?

Comment: Do you want to know how to drop a particular type of object, or a whole user and schema?

Answer (score 1):

The following statement drops the user, jones and all associated objects and foreign keys that depend on the tables owned by jones.

```
DROP USER jones CASCADE;
```

[Oracle® Database Security Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm)